# configure dismax requesthandlar for boost a field

Tags: boost, requesthandler, dismax, solr-boost

I want to apply boost for searching. i want that if a query term occur both in description,name than docs having query term in description field come high in search results. for this i configure dismax request handler as:

```xml
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.DisMaxRequestHandler" default="true"  >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <float name="tie">0.01</float>
        <str name="qf">
            text^0.5 name^1.0 description^1.5 
        </str>
        <str name="fl">
            UID_PK,name,price,description
        </str>
        <str name="mm">
            2&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;90%
        </str>
        <int name="ps">100</int>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
        <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
        <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
        <str name="f.text.hl.fragmenter">regex</str> <!-- defined below -->
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

But i am not finding any effect in my search results. do i need to do some more configuration to see the effect.

Comment: Please post the http query you are making to the Solr server